# Multiple Master Challenge | MySQL & MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-slave

We have some 5 different instances of MySQL where we are collecting data but we are also building warehouse system for that we need to consolidate all data under one instance in a big machine. But MySQL does not provide multi-master replication so do we have any option left to consolidate? I have been searching on web and found some solution that **MariaDB Galera** provides multiple-master replication and good thing about it is being completely compatible with MySQL files.

Can it be possible to make **MySQL** instance as master and MariaDB instance as Slave? so if that is anyway possible, MariaDB will essentially be slave of multiple MySQL masters.

Please suggest if there can be other option best suited for this situation.

Comment: Why you are do not want migrate to MariaDB full?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a MySQL server and a MariaDB slave. Also, MariaDB allows for multi-source replication, which in your case should be useful.

You can have a MariaDB slave instance and set all 5 of your MySQL instances as masters to this instance.

[This](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/replication/standard-replication/setting-up-replication/) link can help you set up the replication from a single master. To add more masters just use the 'CHANGE MASTER TO' command and use different master addresses.

Example

To add two masters, use

```
CHANGE MASTER "source_1" TO 
  MASTER_HOST='XXX.XXX.XXX.XX1',
  MASTER_USER='replication_user',
  MASTER_PORT=3306,
  MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
  MASTER_LOG_POS=564,
  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10;

CHANGE MASTER "source_2" TO 
  MASTER_HOST='XXX.XXX.XXX.XX2',
  MASTER_USER='slave_user',
  MASTER_PASSWORD='password',
  MASTER_PORT=3306,
  MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002',
  MASTER_LOG_POS=107,
  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10;
```

This should create a multi-source instance in MariaDB which will consolidate data from all your sources.

To view all your sources, run the `SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS` command from your slave MariaDB instance.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10 supports multi-source replication, which means that one MariaDB server has many masters from which it replicates.

> You specify which master connection you want to work with by either specifying the connection name in the command or setting default_master_connection to the connection you want to work with.
>
> The connection name may include any characters and should be less than 64 characters. Connection names are compared without regard to case (case insensitive). You should preferably keep the connection name short as it will be used as a suffix for relay logs and master info index files.

Source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/replication/standard-replication/multi-source-replication/

Guide: https://mariadb.com/blog/high-availability-multi-source-replication-mariadb-100

Comment: so my question was can a MariaDB slave be replicated from one or more MySQL Instance? If yes, it will solve my problem!